# How to use built-in icons for language contributions in a VSCode Extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I would like to use one of those built-in Icons at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels

#### package.json

```json
...
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [{
      ...
      "icon": {
        "dark": "$(account)",
        "light": "$(account)"
    }
    ...
...
```

Results in no icon at all:

[image: no icon]

I also tried `account`, `$(accounts-view-bar-icon)` and `accounts-view-bar-icon`. All those different syntaxes and ID's are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution but not sure if that is the correct way.

- Install the Codicons ( https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-codicons ) to the extension via `npm i @vscode/codicons`
- Copy the icons you want to use from `./node_modules/@vscode/codicons/src/icons` to `./src/icons`
- Copy them one for `dark` and one for `light`
- Use the icons in the `package.json` file like:

```json
 "icon": {
  "dark": "./src/icons/dark/account.svg",
  "light": "./src/icons/light/account.svg"
}
```

- Change the colors in the `.svg` files at `./icons/dark/account.svg` and `./icons/light/account.svg`:

```html
<svg
  width="16"
  height="16"
  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  fill="#478af5"> ...
```

```html
<svg
  width="16"
  height="16"
  viewBox="0 0 16 16"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  fill="#1f2b40"> ...
```

##### Note on color changes for Icons

If you change the color of an icon afterwards, change the name of the used icon in the `package.json` to any other value, package your Extension, change it back to the origin icon name and package again. Otherwise the color changes will not take place in VSCode. Seems it will be cached.